# How can I access a global variable in a function I'm importing

Tags: python, global-variables

here is the top of the code...

```
import sys
import requests
import datetime
import json
import user_functions
from time import sleep
now = datetime.datetime.now()
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

importgroups = ['staff']
key = ""
```

In the user_functions file I have a function:

```
def TDactionuser(bcchangess):
    global key
    print key
    global importgroups
    if bcchangess['primary_affiliation'] not in importgroups:
        return
```

The rub of the issue is that I can't seem to access the key or import groups variables. I'm not sure how to get around this. I use global and not global and well....it says that they are not defined.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./userupload.py", line 66,
>   in 
>       user_functions.TDactionuser(bcchangess)   File "/TDPROXY/USERIMP/user_functions.py", line 12, in TDactionuser
>       print key NameError: global name 'key' is not defined

Any help with this will be appreciated...

Comment: "global" means *module level* in Python. `TDactionuser`'s global scope is the top-level scope in `user_functions`, not where you *call* `TDactionuser`. In any event, you shouldn't use global variables. This is a great example of the beginnings of spaghetti code. **Just pass and return parameters**.

Comment: if trying to access the variable from another file, you need to `import` it

Comment: But in importing the functions into file1

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
def TDactionuser(bcchangess):
    from __main__ import key
    from __main__ import importgroups
    print key
    if bcchangess['primary_affiliation'] not in importgroups:
        return
```

But generally that is a bad design